# Inject javascript in c# web browser / Chrome console

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to inject javascript code into my c# web browser. It should act just like the chrome console when you right click inside chrome and then click inspect. Here is a gif of what it should act like:
https://gyazo.com/f9c8d1e158a5694fad3fc9589e981963

Thanks!

Edit:
Here is something I've already tried:

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = "function sayHello() { alert('hello') }";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");
```

That worked but after I attempted to change my code to what I want it to do I got a bunch of errors.

Comment: Start coding and when you run into a problem, then post it here.

Comment: I have done everything else I just can't get this to work